# Possible for Lync (Skype for Business) to adopt Activesync-style policies?

Tags: email, mobile, compliance, corporate-policy, lync

My compliance manager recently told me that Lync IMs should be treated as e-mail for compliance purposes.

This also made me realize that our other email policies (encrypted device, pin required, etc) should also be adopted for this form of communication.

Is there any way to get a Lync client (or comparable/compatible 3rd party) to adopt Activesync-style encryption policies?

Comment: This might be a better fit at serverfault since it is a specific question to the config of a specific commercial software

Comment: @schroeder I'm OK with the move - what happens to the bounty (doesn't matter really to me)

Comment: I've never used Lync/Skype for Business/ActiveSync, so I may be off base here, but can't you require that your user must also setup the corresponding Exchange mail account with ActiveSync on devices that runs Lync. Most of the device and account policies probably would apply the same on both and the email policies probably can't really be directly applied to IM anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I last worked closely with Lync server, but while you can exercise quite a bit of control over the content of the conversations, I don't believe that it directly allows for Activesync style encryption policies.  I sadly no longer have a configured environment to go digging on to verify that though, so take this answer with a large grain of salt as a fair bit speculative.